# Application of the Pythagorean Theorem in Word Problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

[image]

When you follow the link above, you'll find that the image shows 2 poles set up in a room with two boxes set up to run along them. Pole 1 is parallel to the west and east walls while pole 2 is parallel to the north and south walls. All measurements of each are shown in the image. Box 1 starts at the end of Pole 1 and Box 2 starts at the end of Pole 2.

1. Find n (the distance between Box 2 and Box 1)
2. The boxes begin running along the poles at the same time at a speed of 0.3km/h. What is the direct distance between them after two seconds?
3. During the first 14 secs, calculate the smallest possible distance between the boxes while they run along the poles and the exact time at which this happens.

I calculated that the answer to the first question would be 38.4057 metres while the answer to the second question would be 25.9808 metres. However, I don't know how to work out the answer to the last question. Help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Find position of box $1$ and box $2$ after $t$ seconds. (speed of each is 5/6 m/sec). Now find the distance between the boxes in terms of t. Differentiate. Find $t$. Use the $t$ that is less than or equal to 14 sec.

Comment: But are my answers to the first two questions correct?

Comment: @sku also, if I use your method, it won't let me find the exact time (to 2.d.p) as I will be working with whole numbers and essentially, using the guess and check method. Are there any other strategic approaches?

Answer (score 1):

Let the segment joining top of box 1 and box 2 be AB. 
Let the segment joining bottom of box 1 and box 2 be CD.

In time $t$, A and B would have moved $5t/6$.

Consider segment CD as a function of time $t$.

$CD^2(t) = (25 - 5t/6)^2 + (15-5t/6)^2$

So $AB^2(t) = (25 - 5t/6)^2 + (15-5t/6)^2 +5^2$ ... Eqn(1)

Plug $t =0$ for question $1$ and $t=2$ for Q2.

For $3$;  differentiate. $-125/3 + 25t/18 -75/3 + 25t/18 =0$

You get $t=24$

But we want min distance within $14$sec. So plug $t=14$ in the distance Eqn(1)

Comment: I don't really understand this method. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Since it involves this complex picture, I dont know how to explain. Hopefully someone in the community can do a better job. However, let me know which part you dont understand.